# Extracting integers from dataframe.min() series object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I am trying to use Pandas to evaluate the minimum value in a dataframe column and then run an evaluative statement (if this, then that) on the variable. However, it is not possible to evaluate a series object. How do you pull a numerical value out of a Pandas series object?

```
    for file_ in postFiles:
        df2 = pd.read_csv(file_, header=0, delimiter=';', usecols=[0,1,2])
        ymax = df2[['xvalue']].max(numeric_only=True)
        ymin = df2[['yvalue']].min(numeric_only=True)
        print(ymax)
        print(ymin)

        if ymax > ymin:
        print ('hello')
```

This is my code as an example.

I get the following error when I run this:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: `max` and `min` return a `Series` you want the scalar value from the array try this: `ymax = df2[['xvalue']].max(numeric_only=True)[0]
        ymin = df2[['yvalue']].min(numeric_only=True)[0]`

Comment: Perfect @EdChum, just the answer I needed - thanks very much for the quick reply!